# The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

[phpMyAdmin Error: The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047169/phpmyadmin-error-the-mbstring-extension-is-missing-please-check-your-php-confi)

I have already tried all of the solutions on this and none of them have worked for me. I am not sure what else to do.

Comment: well .. is mbstring installed and enabled for your installation ?
Please provide more details .. 1.) What server ( nginx/apache ) , what version of PHP, is it mod-php or php-fpm ?

Comment: Well I fixed that problem , by showing hidden extensions and my php.ini file was actually php.ini.ini, but now I am getting:  The mysqli|mysql extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. See our documentation for more information. I am using xampp

Comment: I have these in my extensions:


extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mssql.dll
extension=mysqli.so
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll       Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll

Comment: hidden extensions?? what operating system is it ? what distribution ? I can't help you without more details

Comment: Please pass the output of installed extensions from php_info

Comment: Umm i looked up a video that was saying something about hidden extensions might be causing it, so I saw php.ini when it was actually php.ini.ini, so I deleted one of the .ini's and it solved my first problem. This is windows 10, and I'm not sure what you mean by distribution. I put in the extension=php_mssql.dll  and the extension=mysqli.so which should cover both of my problems , but it is not. they are also both uncommented

Comment: php_mssql + php_mysqli , what about php_mysql ? .. If it says the extension doesn't exist it means it's not loaded .. please add the list of loaded extensions you get from php_info(); to your question

Comment: How exactly do I do that ? Do I just run phpinfo.php? Sorry I am all new to this.

Comment: Create a new PHP document that says <?php phpinfo(); ?> and open it.. It will have a list of actual loaded extensions

Comment: Welp I just got on today and it magically worked, haven't touched a thing. Just went ahead and tried it and it worked. So I have not a clue as to what I did.

Comment: You probably already fix the problem didn't restart/reload php/apache when you did one of the changes ...
sounds to me like you just make loads of mistakes working with it so it looks random but it's just a long collection of mistakes .. you'll get it over time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this problem. This error appears when I upgraded by 15.10 to 16.04 or installed 16.04.I resolved my problem by running this command and system restart. Just run these command

`sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext`

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Or you can follow this post...

[Check This Post](http://www.dailytechnoblog.com/how-to-resolve-phpmyadmin-error-the-mbstring-extension-is-missing-please-check-your-php-configuration/)

Answer (score 0):

It had worked for me - for `xamp3.2.2` `php7.0.1`
changes in `php.ini`

1- `extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext" //give the full path where your ext folder is located`

2- `;extension=php_mysqli.dll //uncomment this (remove semicolon)`

3- `save` and `restart` apache !

Answer (score 0):

I was in a hurry so it's not necessarily the best solution, however it's really very simple,

None of the answers worked for me on stackoverflow

I simply changed windows user session,

Uninstall and install MAMP on this new session and everything worked again

Answer (score -2):

I spent a lot of time trying all the options. Finally solved it by moving the php.ini file back to the php folder from the apache folder that I had moved it to after installing php.