# The mysqli|mysql extension is missing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I cannot find a way to solve this. I have done pretty much everything I can think of, I am kind of new to this stuff, so sometimes I am not sure I am doing it right. I have xampp and am trying to use phpmyadmin to work with databases. I have added the extensions:

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mssql.dll
;extension=mysqli.so
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll       Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      ; Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client

extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite_external.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How shall we say? Did you restart the http server after changing the configuration? What does the famous test script `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` say? Are the extensions installed on your system at all? _Why_ do you claim that the extension is missing?

Comment: restart your web-server.

Comment: You should post one question on per issue. This question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056214/the-mbstring-extension-is-missing-please-check-your-php-configuration, should be deleted; or updated and delete this question.

Comment: Or instead of the dated PhpMyAdmin, use [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/), which utilizes PDO.

Comment: @mario Which does not make any difference at all for this question.

Comment: Did you install php via wamp ?

Comment: @arkascha In regard to its off-topicness, no.

Comment: @PedroLobito i used xampp

Comment: @mario is it better to just use Adminer? and what is this? as said before I am new!

Comment: @arkashca i ran that code and it came up with a document sort of thing with a lot of information in it, am I looking for a certain thing in here?

Comment: You're not actually asking anything because you're not showing us what you want to do, what errors you get or anything.

Comment: The very top line is the error im getting

Answer (score 0):

Strange, because `php` comes with the `mysqli` extension as part of it's core extensions.

1 - Make sure the file `php_mysqli.dll` exists in:

`drive:\xamp_install_dir\bin\php\php<phpversion>\ext\`

if so, copy the following line to your `php.ini`

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

---

2 - Restart `apache`, and create a file named `test.php` with the following content:

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

---

3 - Open it on your browser a search for :

[image]

---

4 - **Found it?**

**Yes:** Good, you're ready to go.

**No:**  You may need to [re-install wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

---

**NOTE:**

Don't worry about `php_mysql.dll` because it's deprecated.

Comment: okay I am using xampp tho, does this mean anything different ?

Comment: It shouldn't, just find the php  **ext** folder

Comment: I could not find mysqli in the phpinfo(); when I ran it and I do have the extension=php_mysqli.dll  in my php.ini file

Comment: Did you find `php_mysqli.dll` ? Which version of php are you running ?

Comment: Yes I did in the C:\xampp\php\ext , also PHP Version 5.6.12, and I am not sure, but on my laptop phpmyadmin is working and I just copied the php.ini I have on my laptop and it's still not working so wouldnt that mean that it is not my ini file?

Comment: You **shouldn't** copy a `php.ini` from a different computer, this will lead to errors. Use the original `php.ini`, include the module line and restart apache, you'll be ok.

Comment: I put in the extension=php_mysqli.dll  and it is still not working. getting same 'The mysqli|mysql extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration' problem

Comment: where is located the `php.ini` you're editing ? You may also find another `php.ini` in `c:\windows\system32\php.ini` check that one too.

Comment: There was no php.ini in the c:\windows\system32\ , the one I am working on is C:\xampp\php\php.ini

Comment: The easiest thing will probably be to reinstall wamp.

Comment: Okay I shall do that then get back with you!