# Fedora phpMyAdmin error: The mbstring extension is missing

Tags: php, apache, php-extension, mbstring

[The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056214/the-mbstring-extension-is-missing-please-check-your-php-configuration)

I have installed LAMP on Fedora following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WT8L2Bm8bV8&t=9s) with some change, The installation finished with no problem. But when I tried to access `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`, this error notify appear. I have already search on google and try all option on the thread linked above.

I changed php.ini configuration:

```
extension=mbstring.so
```

where the extension dir is like this

```
extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules"
```

[This are the Extensions on /usr/lib64/php/modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVWWe.png)

Comment: Have you restarted the apache process to reload the config?

Comment: yeah,, i did several times.. but I just find out. I need do restart php-fpm

Comment: No, I did on right file. But I didn't know that we need to run other command.. But thanks, it's already solved.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [article](https://notulensiku.com/2016/04/phpmyadmin-mbstring-extension-is-missing-centos-7/), I found out that we need restart php-fpm, this solution not mentioned on other tutorial/thread that I have been read.

just run:

```
systemctl restart php-fpm
```

Comment: You, Sir, are genius.