# PHP: No php.ini file

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp, wampserver

I just started to learn PHP and in order to do that I installed wampserver on my windows 8.1. When I try to launch, it works properly but I have two problems:

1) I have an error in my localhost page:

> *** ERROR *** The PHP configuration loaded file is: - should be: C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.17/bin/php.ini or c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.16/phpforapache.ini

I tried to find the php.ini file but it doesn't exist. In my phpinfo() it is (none) in front of Loaded Configuration file.

2) The other problem is I can't access phpmyadmin and I get this error :

> "The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration."

Since I'm really new in php, please keep the answers simple! :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not really a PHP problem as much as it is a WAMP configuration issue.  I'm not sure this is the right place for this question.

Answer (score 16):

I just solve this problem.

1. to be sure to start Wampserver "As an administrator," :

   right-click the shortcuts, Properties, tab Shortcut:

   - Select "Run as administrator"
   - OK
   - Apply
2. Leave Wampmanager and ursing win+x+a or others ways to open a cmd administrator command window.( attention：it should run the cmd as an administrator)
3. In this window, access to your apache installed path
   for exemple, my path: D:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin
4. then type

   > D:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin> mklink php.ini d:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.15\phpForApache.ini

   and you will see a message likes"php.ini << === >> d:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.15\phpForApache.ini symlink created"
5. close the cmd and restart Wampmanager as an administrator

I hope that my solution also works for you.

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks xiao! I've never made a symlink via command prompt before.... To elaborate on this answer, open cmd as administrator, cd to the WAMP Apache bin folder, and type "mklink php.ini C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.15\phpForApache.ini" (without quotes). Walla! No more php.ini error!

Comment: This solution fixed my PHP error in WAMP on Windows 10, too: `mklink php.ini c:\Server\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.16\phpForApache.ini`!

Answer (score 2):

after installation of php you must rename file php-production.ini to php.ini. Those files in your root php directory installed.

For mbstring you must enable this extension. For that you must uncomment the line in your php.ini file (renamed just before) :

```
;extension = php_mbstring.dll
```

Check if you have this line in your php.ini :

```
[mbstring] 
mbstring.language = all 
mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8 
mbstring.http_input = auto 
mbstring.http_output = UTF-8 
mbstring.encoding_translation = On 
mbstring.detect_order = UTF-8 
mbstring.substitute_character = none; 
mbstring.func_overload = 0 
mbstring.strict_encoding = Off
```

Comment: I found the mbstring lines but  there's no extension = php_mbstring.dll

Comment: `php_mbstring.dll` is in `php.ini` uncommented but it still not working!

Answer (score 1):

in system tray (bottom right corner of windows) left click wamp icon, php, version, and click on the current version (the one marked with green tick)

Comment: worked for me. thank you! This is the quickest solution for wampserver.

Answer (score 1):

This was my issue: 
*** ERROR *** The PHP configuration loaded file is: c:/program files (x86)/php/php.ini - should be: c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.27/bin/php.ini or c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.31/phpforapache.ini
You must perform: Right-click icon Wampmanager -> Refresh 
To resolve this issue, I just went into program files(x86) and added 1 to my PHP folder to make this invisible and retarted all Wampserver services it worked fine. Could have been a conflit with my This old PHP.