# Apache localhost already used?! Could not reliably determine the server’s fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName"

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have a problem, I had apache Solr installed and it uses localhost for access on  webserver...

now I have installed Apache and startet httpd.exe and I get the warning / error:
Could not reliably determine the server’s fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName"

when I stop solr, I can start and use localhost for apache httpd...
but I want to have the possibility to use both webservices, how can I configure Apache to do that? and get access to service not with localhost, but with another domain name or some configuration in httpd.conf
I tried to change the line "ServerName www.example.com:80" in httpd.conf file but no effect,

sorry but I'm pretty new to webservers and Apache, how should I configure that?

Answer (score 1):

You have several things mixed here:

1. Installing Solr should in no way be related to other questions, unless it is configured to run on port 80. If that is the case, you simply can not run two services on the same port so you have to pick, or just move Solr to 8080 or whatever.
2. `Could not reliably determine...` is just a friendly warning and will not prevent any functionality, and it should disappear when you add `ServerName www.example.com:80` in httpd.conf
3. With default settings, Apache will respond to any http request that comes to port 80, so you don't have to configure anything there (and if you want to modify that, use `VirtualHost`). You can achieve reaching your webserver by other hostnames by editing [hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Location_in_the_file_system) file on your machine. If you want others to be able to do that, you have to configure DNS (which is separate issue)

Comment: damn I did everything as was said in a tutorial, installed php as module, and copied phpmyadmin folder into htdocs folder of Apache 2.4 and I get this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc:177 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc(282): _encode('The %s extensio...') #1 C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc(289): _gettext('The %s extensio...') #2 C:\Apache24\htdocs\

Comment: That really seems unrelated to your original question :)

Comment: ok I installed another version of phpmyadmin, now it seems to work but I get error "php_mbstring is missing" altough I activated it in the php.ini file... the thing is, I have apache solr installed, but deactivated all services to it, I dont understand how it tries maybe to get access to the mbstring of the apache solr config, therefore it doesnt work? is there some kind of conflict?

Comment: What leads you to think that error is related to solr?

Comment: hm no idea, I recognised it is not related to Solr, I just watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVkYzAIl4Ts and thought it would be similar, related to other program like Wamp (Bitnami) or so... but however I solved it now by following this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047169/phpmyadmin-error-the-mbstring-extension-is-missing-please-check-your-php-confi   and I changed extension dir "C:\php\ext" and then it worked... this apache kind of stuff is really annoying, feels like a patchwork rug...

Comment: the error on my comment above _mb_detect_encoding() was also related to the wrong path resolution, not to the phpmyadmin version