# phpmyadmin stopped working on WAMPserver

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, wamp

i have installed WAMP 3 and it has bee working without any issues for the past few months... Since yesterday there is a problem

When i open the phpmyadmin i get the below error

```
phpMyAdmin - Error
The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
```

and when i access any codeigniter page i get this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()
```

It worked perfectly until yesterday. I didnt install any new software's or upgrade anything

What i have done so far:
-through WAMP the mysqli and mbstring extensions are enabled. Its also uncommnted
-the extension path has been set correctly
-the ext folder has all the necessary DLL files

Can someone please tell me what might be causing this? im unable to work on my localhost

Comment: Restart apache and try again.

Comment: @Harikrishnan did it over 3 times and restarted my PC several times too :(

Comment: This question/error has already been post here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047169/phpmyadmin-error-the-mbstring-extension-is-missing-please-check-your-php-confi

Do you have correct path include_path= "C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\PEAR\.     Are you sure you have php-mbstring lib ? Did you double check that all the path are correct in your php.ini, did you upgrade your wamp version ?

Comment: @davidbonachera  i dont have a folder called `PEAR` in my php folder and the include path is commented. Yes that dll file is inside the `ext` folder . This path is set `extension_dir ="C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.15/ext/"` . I did upgrade WAMP last year.. But it was working until yesterday

Comment: Which version of php are you using ? 5.6.15 ? try to run `php -i`

Comment: its the `phpinfo()` right?

Comment: @davidbonachera i checked the phpinfo. Its odd the config path shows `Configuration File (php.ini) Path  C:\Windows` and there is no `php.ini` in the windows folder

Comment: Do a `php --ini` and look at the line titled `Loaded Configuration File:` Or the same title in `phpinfo()`

Comment: Try this: `Right click the wampmanager icon -> Refresh`

Comment: Just a thought: I find using xampp is better on windows than wamp hardly any errors

Comment: @wolfgang1983 They are very similar, but not if you want 64bit or to be able to switch between multiple versions of PHP/Apache/MySQL available at the touch of a menu!

Comment: @LiveEn Are you getting anywhere?

Comment: @RiggsFolly finally got it sorted...i deleted the php.ini files and created them from a fresh file and restarted WAMP and it worked