# I can't access my XAMPP local server because of phpMyAdmin - Error The mbstring extension is missing

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm having trouble on my XAMPP server. How to fix this error: **phpMyAdmin - Error The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.**

I'm using **XAMPP v3.2.2** 
My xampp is place in drive ** C:\ **

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate question of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047169/phpmyadmin-error-the-mbstring-extension-is-missing-please-check-your-php-confi

Comment: Go to the `php.ini` file and add the extension line. If mbstring was not compiled with PHP, then recompile with it.