# after a while I opened phpmyadmin and this appeared on ubuntu 17

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-server

getHeader(); $scripts = $header->getScripts(); $scripts->addFile('jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js'); $scripts->addFile('jquery/jquery.uitablefilter.js'); $scripts->addFile('tbl_change.js'); $scripts->addFile('indexes.js'); $scripts->addFile('gis_data_editor.js'); $scripts->addFile('multi_column_sort.js'); /** * Set ajax_reload in the response if it was already set */ if (isset($ajax_reload) && $ajax_reload['reload'] === true) { $response->addJSON('ajax_reload', $ajax_reload); } /** * Defines the url to return to in case of error in a sql statement */ $is_gotofile = true; if (empty($goto)) { if (empty($table)) { $goto = Util::getScriptNameForOption( $GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultTabDatabase'], 'database' ); } else { $goto = Util::getScriptNameForOption( $GLOBALS['cfg']['DefaultTabTable'], 'table' ); } } // end if if (! isset($err_url)) { $err_url = (! empty($back) ? $back : $goto) . '?' . PMA_URL_getCommon(array('db' => $GLOBALS['db'])) . ((mb_strpos(' ' . $goto, 'db_') != 1 && mb_strlen($table)) ? '&table=' . urlencode($table) : '' ); } // end if // Coming from a bookmark dialog if (isset($_POST['bkm_fields']['bkm_sql_query'])) { $sql_query = $_POST['bkm_fields']['bkm_sql_query']; } elseif (isset($_GET['sql_query'])) { $sql_query = $_GET['sql_query']; } // This one is just to fill $db if (isset($_POST['bkm_fields']['bkm_database'])) { $db = $_POST['bkm_fields']['bkm_database']; } // During grid edit, if we have a relational field, show the dropdown for it. if (isset($_REQUEST['get_relational_values']) && $_REQUEST['get_relational_values'] == true ) { PMA_getRelationalValues($db, $table); // script has exited at this point } // Just like above, find possible values for enum fields during grid edit. if (isset($_REQUEST['get_enum_values']) && $_REQUEST['get_enum_values'] == true) { PMA_getEnumOrSetValues($db, $table, "enum"); // script has exited at this point } // Find possible values for set fields during grid edit. if (isset($_REQUEST['get_set_values']) && $_REQUEST['get_set_values'] == true) { PMA_getEnumOrSetValues($db, $table, "set"); // script has exited at this point } if (isset($_REQUEST['get_default_fk_check_value']) && $_REQUEST['get_default_fk_check_value'] == true ) { $response = Response::getInstance(); $response->addJSON( 'default_fk_check_value', Util::isForeignKeyCheck() ); exit; } /** * Check ajax request to set the column order and visibility */ if (isset($_REQUEST['set_col_prefs']) && $_REQUEST['set_col_prefs'] == true) { PMA_setColumnOrderOrVisibility($table, $db); // script has exited at this point } // Default to browse if no query set and we have table // (needed for browsing from DefaultTabTable) $tableLength = mb_strlen($table); $dbLength = mb_strlen($db); if (empty($sql_query) && $tableLength && $dbLength) { $sql_query = PMA_getDefaultSqlQueryForBrowse($db, $table); // set $goto to what will be displayed if query returns 0 rows $goto = ''; } else { // Now we can check the parameters Util::checkParameters(array('sql_query')); } /** * Parse and analyze the query */ require_once 'libraries/parse_analyze.lib.php'; list( $analyzed_sql_results, $db, $table_from_sql ) = PMA_parseAnalyze($sql_query, $db); // @todo: possibly refactor extract($analyzed_sql_results); if ($table != $table_from_sql && !empty($table_from_sql)) { $table = $table_from_sql; } /** * Check rights in case of DROP DATABASE * * This test may be bypassed if $is_js_confirmed = 1 (already checked with js) * but since a malicious user may pass this variable by url/form, we don't take * into account this case. */ if (PMA_hasNoRightsToDropDatabase( $analyzed_sql_results, $cfg['AllowUserDropDatabase'], $is_superuser )) { Util::mysqlDie( __('"DROP DATABASE" statements are disabled.'), '', false, $err_url ); } // end if /** * Need to find the real end of rows? */ if (isset($find_real_end) && $find_real_end) { $unlim_num_rows = PMA_findRealEndOfRows($db, $table); } /** * Bookmark add */ if (isset($_POST['store_bkm'])) { PMA_addBookmark($goto); // script has exited at this point } // end if /** * Sets or modifies the $goto variable if required */ if ($goto == 'sql.php') { $is_gotofile = false; $goto = 'sql.php' . PMA_URL_getCommon( array( 'db' => $db, 'table' => $table, 'sql_query' => $sql_query ) ); } // end if PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse( $analyzed_sql_results, // analyzed_sql_results $is_gotofile, // is_gotofile $db, // db $table, // table isset($find_real_end) ? $find_real_end : null, // find_real_end isset($import_text) ? $import_text : null, // sql_query_for_bookmark isset($extra_data) ? $extra_data : null, // extra_data isset($message_to_show) ? $message_to_show : null, // message_to_show isset($message) ? $message : null, // message isset($sql_data) ? $sql_data : null, // sql_data $goto, // goto $pmaThemeImage, // pmaThemeImage isset($disp_query) ? $display_query : null, // disp_query isset($disp_message) ? $disp_message : null, // disp_message isset($query_type) ? $query_type : null, // query_type $sql_query, // sql_query isset($selected) ? $selected : null, // selectedTables isset($complete_query) ? $complete_query : null // complete_query ); 
some advice? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after updating ubuntu to 17.10. Apache2 and php were not correctly installed.
Run :

```
sudo apt install --reinstall php7.1 libapache2-mod-php7.1
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You may need to update apache2 and (re)install some libs (I lost mbstring for instance). If so, check this post : [phpMyAdmin Error: The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047169/phpmyadmin-error-the-mbstring-extension-is-missing-please-check-your-php-confi)