# Phpmyadmin showing mbstring is missing

Tags: php, mbstring

I have using `PHP 7.2` version,and modules list is given below:

```
php -m

[PHP Modules]

bz2
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
Phar
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sodium
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

In this list it shows `mbstring` but in `info.php` on browser it doesn't has `mbstring` when i searched ...anyone please help me for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [phpMyAdmin Error: The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047169/phpmyadmin-error-the-mbstring-extension-is-missing-please-check-your-php-confi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cli` and `apache` or `nginx` module have different config paths and, probably, different configs. Your module is enabled on `cli` but disabled to `web`.

You need to check your `php.ini`

If you try to do this (on terminal):

```
$ php -a
phpinfo();
```

In a point you can see the `php.ini` path.

Do the same thing on your `www` directory creating a `phpinfo.php` and calling the `phpinfo()` function and check the `php.ini` path.

Probably is not the same path and not the same configurations because we have a `ini` file to `cli` and to the `apache/nginx` module. So, you can fix it seeing which file is loading the modules and point to enable the module on web.

If is in different path, probably you'll need to enable or install the `mbstring` module on web version.

Considering that you're using `php-fpm` you can install `mbstring` module with the following command:

`php-fpm install mbstring`

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path  - /etc/php/7.2/fpm ...this is showing in info.php on browser sir...

Comment: in terminal,below command given
php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.2/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
it shows that cli/php.ini file is loading but in browser info.php loaded configuration file is showing /fpm/php.ini file ...

Comment: Yes, different paths, different configurations. You'll need to enable mbstring on your `fpm` installation. Look at the `modules.conf`

Answer (score 0):

In case of **Windows**,

1. Edit the `php.ini` file
2. update `extension_dir = "ext" to extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"` （may vary based on your system）
3. Remove `semicolon` from `;extension=php_mbstring.dll` and change it to `extension=php_mbstring.dll`
4. You also need to enable mcrypt as well by uncomment/remove **semicolon** from `;extension=php_mcrypt.dll`. (Generally phpmyadmin also gives error for `mcrypt`)
5. Save your php.ini file
6. Restart the apache server

For **ubuntu**,

1. Open terminal
2. Enter command `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext libapache2-mod-php7.0`
3. Restart apache `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

If above method doesn't work, explicitly enable mbstring and mcrypt extensions:

```
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
sudo phpenmod mbstring
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Hope it works for you!!